# Equality between double factorial and binomial coefficient

Tags: binomial-coefficients, factorial

I read this formula, but I don't think it's right
$$ \binom{1/4}{j} = \frac{(-1)^j(4j-5)!!}{4^j j!} $$

First off, I think that's $(-1)^{j+1}$. Then I have a product like $3\cdot7 \cdot11\cdot15 $. Does this expressed by $(4j-5)!!$?

Comment: You're right, the formula is wrong.  Where did you read it?

Comment: That's a paper of my teacher

Comment: Then you should tell your teacher.